# disable save button when there are error with laravel and vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify v-text-field on a form. I have some basic rules (field required) that I can validate using basic rules **(:rules="[ rules.required ]")**.
But I also have a validation on the server side to enforce uniqueness of this value in the DB. So this can't be validated with simple rules. On my axios call I check for error and set the error-messages **(:error-messages="editedItem.errors['fieldname']")**

I want the save button to be disabled whenever the form is in error ... but the problem is that once I have set the error-messages, then **the form is always in error**.

How can I reset it?

I could probably reset the editedItem.errors array every time there is a change on the field. But I find it overkill.

Is there an easier way ?

Comment: I have added @focus:"resetErrors('field')" and reset the errors[] for that field. At least it does it only on focus, not on every change. Do you have a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

@focus did the trick for me for now.